# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header Error on jQuery.getJSON()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, model-view-controller

I have a GET method in a rest api `A` that returns a list of string[]

In my website `B`, I have a web page. I want to autocomplete an input text with the string values I got from web api `A`

I put my web API `A` on IIS and binded it to `localhost:9000`

Website `B`:

```
<input type="text" id="tags"/>

$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        jQuery.getJSON(                   
            "http://localhost:9000/action/controller",
            function (data) { 
                alert(data);
                data = jQuery.unique(data)
                response(data);
            }
        );
    }, 
    select: function (event, ui) { 
        //work here
    },
});
```

When I run website `B`, it takes port `60400` by default

and so when I write in the input `id="tags"` I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/action/controller. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:60400' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: you have to allow your ui server  from data server. please google cross domain access

Comment: For temporary testing purpose over local you can use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en extesion on chrome.

Comment: By the way on which server you are working.

Answer (score 2):

You are obviously facing a problem because the webSite A does not have the same domain (a.k.a. origin), as the service it calls. You have to enable CORS on your web-service in order to make it work.
I suggest you read this article: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

For security-reasons, cross-origin requests are not being served by applications that are not eplicitly configured to do so. On the .NET Stack you can use the Cors Nuget-Package, which will make enabling CORS as easy as 2 lines of additional code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your header on the server side. Something like this (web.config):

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:9000" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

1. Very good example of using CORS with explanation you can find here:
   [CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server)
2. If I remember correctly CORS requires `xhr.withCredentials = true;` so I would rather use native `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` or if you wish jQuery.
3. Any cross-domain call requires 2 requests (1st with verb OPTIONS, and 2nd request itself). But second request will go only if 1st one return provision header from server.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the required headers are attached to the server. You can create a `preflight` request or a `simple` request depending on the data that you want to process. Unless your server has the required headers, your client won't be allowed the access. This is due to the `Same origin policy`. Please do some research on `CORS`, which is one of the ways to bypass `same origin policy`. 
On my server side, i am allowing the origin using a `preflight` request and `withCredentials` value as `true`. Also, i am using `AJAX` to first create a pre-flight request and then the `POST` method is triggered.

[HTML5rocks CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) is an excellent article to understand the functioning of CORS.

This is the server side code that goes in my server config.

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:9002" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
```